# Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate to a matching parenthesis/bracket?

Tags: keyboard

I use Mathematica on a Mac. If I place the text cursor in the middle of some text/maths and press ALT $\rightarrow$ or ALT $\leftarrow$, the cursor moves forwards or backwards (respectively) one full "word", like it does on regular word processors. (Presumably there is a similar shortcut on Windows, perhaps CTRL $\rightarrow$ and CTRL $\leftarrow$.)

When working with really big expressions, sometimes finding the parenthesis or bracket matching the selected (highlighted) one and navigating to it is a pain. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried the menu item `Edit | Check Balance` or the equivalent keyboard short cut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>?

Comment: @CarlWoll That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :) Can you please add your solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Rain Might find this of use: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1855244?p_p_auth=nOt8yevW

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for the menu item `Edit | Check Balance` or the equivalent keyboard short-cut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.